# Specifying NOT NULL when writing pandas to SQL

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm creating a table using SQLAlchemy like this:

```
import sqlalchemy

df.to_sql(table_name, engine, schema='dbo', 
          index=True, index_label='IdColumn', 
          if_exists='replace',
          dtype={'IdColumn': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=255)})
```

Is it possible to specify in `dtypes` that `IdColumn` should be `not null`? The above writes `df` to the SQL-server, but gives `IdColumn` the type `(varchar(255), null)` by default.

Comment: you have to create the column before hand, with the correct metadata fields.

Comment: @Datanovice Surely there must be a way to do it using `to_sql` with `if_exists='replace'`? This basically creates the table, so would seem odd if it isn't possible to specify the option as a user

Comment: you can indeed, if the table does not exist you can create it and set all the correct metadata : check out https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy_core_creating_table.htm i don't have access to my old codebase but i would routinley create most my sql server tables this way

Comment: @Manakin the question is about using pandas' `df.to_sql()` to automatically create the table for you (when using `if_exists='replace'`) with `NOT NULL` columns ("the correct metadata"). The OP is not asking about manually creating tables via SQLAlchemy and setting the correct metadata.